# Multiple game frames in construct 2 for new levels?

Tags: html5, construct-2

Hi there I'm new to Construct and have tried out a few platformer tutorials. I'm getting to grips with setting variables and collisions, I'm now at the stage where I want to start adding new levels. What the best way to effectively go to a new level, I know in flash this would be a new frame on the timeline, what would you do in construct 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the System object's 'Go to layout' action.